# QListView horizontal scrollbars not showing

Tags: python, qlistview

I noticed that after populating a QListView's sourceModel with data, the horizontal scrollbars do not appear? How do i fix this?

Even if i set them to always show, they do not correctly expanded when content exceeds the width of the widget.

I'm guessing the issues is because I'm setting the size hint to the icon size. The reason i do this is so i can control the size of the icon.

[image]

```
import os, sys
import tempfile
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class MyModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self._items = []
        self._iconSize = QtCore.QSize(18, 18)

    def rowCount(self, index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self._items)

    def columnCount(self, index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 1

    def addItem(self, obj):
        self.beginInsertRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), self.rowCount(), self.rowCount())
        self._items.append(obj)
        self.endInsertRows()

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None
        if 0 <= index.row() < self.rowCount():
            item = self._items[index.row()]
            if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
                return item
            elif role == QtCore.Qt.SizeHintRole:
                return self._iconSize

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None,):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(300, 300)

        # controls
        model = QtGui.QSortFilterProxyModel()
        model.setSortCaseSensitivity(QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        model.setSourceModel(MyModel())

        self.ui_list = QtGui.QListView()
        self.ui_list.setEditTriggers(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.ui_list.setModel(model)
        self.ui_list.setWordWrap(False)
        self._populate_model()

        # layout        
        self.setCentralWidget(self.ui_list)


    def _populate_model(self):
        root = tempfile.gettempdir() 
        for f in os.listdir(root):
            self.ui_list.model().sourceModel().addItem(os.path.join(root,f))

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

By default we use the `textElideMode` property enabled in the `QAbstractItemView`(`QListView`), in order to solve this we can establish a delegate and overwrite the `sizeHint()` method, to calculate the width we use `QFontMetrics`:

```
class Delegate(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def sizeHint(self, option, index):
        h = QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate.sizeHint(self, option, index).height()
        text = index.data()
        fm = QtGui.QFontMetrics(option.font)
        w = fm.width(text)
        return QtCore.QSize(w, h)
```

Then the delegate is established:

```
    self.ui_list = QtGui.QListView()
    self.ui_list.setItemDelegate(Delegate(self))
```

[image]